# Basic problems with model theoretic relations

Tags: relations, model-theory, function-and-relation-composition, natural-numbers

I would like to understand [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9906113.pdf) on the page $54$ on the $3$rd line
what does it precisely mean that the two relations are viewed as $${}^n2.$$
What object is that ${}^n2$ and how the relations on it are meant to be interpreted.
It is the case that the sentence

> "relations are viewed as ${}^n 2$"

doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Usually, this is a power tower of $n$ twos , but I di not know if this makes sense in the given context.

Comment: The notation ${}^{X}Y$ means the set of all functions $X\to Y$. In general, I would say the notation $Y^X$ is more common, but the former notation is especially popular among set theorists (and I think Shelah uses it always). The reason is probably that when $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are cardinals, it's often necessary to distinguish between the set of functions $\kappa\to \lambda$ and the cardinal $\lambda^\kappa$. (That's what's going on here: ${}^{n}2$ is a set of functions, not a natural number.)

Comment: The punctuation in the original text is important. It's saying this structure has "two relations: (viewed as ${}^n2$)$\ldots$[definitions of two relations on ${}^n2$]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context ${}^n2$ is the set of all functions from $n$ to $2$.  Also, $n = \{0, 1, ..., n-1\}$, and $2 = \{0, 1\}$.  Since $B_n^3 = \{0, 1, ..., 2^n-1\}$ has cardinality $2^n$, we may identify it with ${}^n2$, and hence use notions like the lexicographic ordering on functions on $B_n^3$.

Also, he's not saying that the relations are being viewed as ${}^n2$, he's saying that to give his definitions of the two relations he will identify $B_n^3$ with ${}^n2$.

Comment: OK. And what does mean $3$ in $B^3_n$ ? And how is the lexicographic order defined: when is $f<_{lx}g$ and from where to where $f$ and $g$ go ?

Comment: Also, what is syntactically $\eta_0$ on the $5$th line ?